# $xay=a^{-1}$ implies $yax=a^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $x,a,y$ are elements in a group $G$ such that $xay=a^{-1}$, then is it always true that $yax=a^{-1}$?

The two equations are equivalent to $xaya=e$ and $yaxa=e$, but I don't know whether these two are equivalent to each other.

Comment: $xay=a^{-1}$, $xaya=1$, $xayax=x$, $ayax=1$, $yax=a^{-1}$.

Comment: how are $x,y$ related??

Comment: By alphabirth. ${}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson How can we garuntee that the x's cancel out in your third part.

Comment: Right multiply by a, right multiply by $x$, left multiply by $x^{-1}$, left multiply by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @Tyler, $x$ is an element in a group, so it has an inverse, by which one is free to multiply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the general fact that

> If $ab = 1$, then $ba = 1$.

To prove this, simply note that $b = a^{-1}$, and it's clear. Now we can simply write

$$xay = a^{-1} \iff (xa)(ya) = 1 \iff (ya)(xa) = 1 \iff yax = a^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ \color{#c00}{\rm Conjugation}$ $\rm\color{#0a0}R$otates: $\,\ \color{#c00}{a_1^{-1}}(\,\color{#c00}a_1 a_2 a_3\cdots a_n =\, 1)\, \color{#c00}{a_1}\ \overset{\rm\color{#0a0} R}\Rightarrow\  a_2 a_3\cdots a_n\color{#c00}{a_1} = 1$

So, twice rotating: $\ xay=a^{-1}\!\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}xaya = 1\, \overset{\rm\color{#0a0} R}\Rightarrow\, \color{#a34}aya\color{#c00}{x} = 1\, \overset{\rm\color{#0a0} R}\Rightarrow\ yax\color{#a34}a=1\,\Rightarrow\,yax = a^{-1}$